# Missing bin/EntityFramework.xml file in Visual Studio 2010 and EF 4.1 DB First

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, deployment

**Main Goal** - To deploy a live version of my solution on an IIS. I am currently attempting to do so by building a deployment package through Visual Studio 2010.

**Issue** - When attempting to build a deployment package or publish my project within Visual Studio 2010, I get an error stating that 'bin/EntityFramework.xml' is missing.

I've done quite a bit of research and have not been able to find any information on how this file could have gone missing or how to restore/regenerate the file.

**Questions** - Is there any way to restore or regenerate the 'bin/EntityFramework.xml' file? Or, is there a simpler approach for deploying my VS 2010 solution to an IIS?

(FYI, I've already attempted copying the file structure to an IIS manually. This caused assembly issues, which is why I'm currently avoiding that approach.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the specific question first, you can easily regenerate this file by creating a new project of the same type (e.g. ASP.NET MVC3), then building that new project. EntityFramework.xml will appear in the new project's bin folder. You may then copy it over to your existing project.

However, you can just 'Exclude from Project' the missing file (via right-click in Solution Explorer), since it is not required to build, then you will achieve your goal of publishing the project through VS2010.